# Working Example of Method Call in richfaces

Tags: jsf, netbeans, oracle11g, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have looked everywhere for the following issue, but unfortunately not able to find the solution. I an using JSF 2.2, richfaces, Netbeans 7.3.1 and GlassFish Server. I am trying to build a GUI for selecting multiple items in the rich:picklist, adding them to the right and clicking a submit button which would execute methods (having JDBC calls) associated with each of the selected items on the right and hence populating the tables in Database. Any working example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see a live demo of all richfaces components here http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/

Here all the components usage and its tag information every thing is clearly given. Still if you feel any problem with understanding then you can post another question with a specific problem. The question you have asked is a very general one. no offense.

Hope above link helps you.

Comment: it is RichFaces 3.3 demo! JSF 2.2 cannot be used with RichFaces 3.3. PickList demo for RichFaces 4.3 is [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList&skin=blueSky)